# Is "A great place to start to move up the ladder" a grammatically correct sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

"A great place to start to move up the ladder"... We are in a quandary because of the sheer magnanimity of the message and importance it conveys.. Looking out for some quick answers regarding its grammatical correctness..

Comment: Good, neatly compressed.  It would be clumsy if the missing words were spelled out: ...a great place **to** **go** **to,** **from** **which** to start (moving *or* ) to move up the ladder.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a sentence because it has no predicate.  It's a noun phrase "a great place" that has an infinitive modifier.  You'll need to supply more to make this a complete thought.  Perhaps:

```
Acme Escalators, Inc is a great place to start to move up the ladder.
```